# Sharpness of Kolmogorov-Chentsov

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, holder-spaces

The [Kolmogorov-Chentsov continuity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem) is a general way to estimate the Hölder continuity of a process $X$ (up to taking a different version $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ ). However, I would like to know if this criterium is optimal. That is, given a process $X:[0,K] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ define:

$$
\alpha :=
\sup\Big\{ \frac{\log \mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^p]}{p\log |t-s|}-\frac{1}{p}  \; \Big| \; t,s \in [0,K], p> 1, \mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^p]<\infty   \Big\}
$$

Then, is it true that there exists no version $\tilde{X}$ of $X$ s.t $\tilde{X}$ is $\alpha$-Hölder? Or maybe, just for $\beta >\alpha$?

For instance, this statement is true for the Brownian Motion, however, at least in the proof I know for such fact uses the exact scaling $B_{at} \sim \sqrt{a}B_t$, however, the moment condition is more general. Is there an additional assumption you need to make the statement true?

I appreciate any references or ideas.

**EDIT:** I suppose the constant I am ignoring is actually going to make a difference. So let me rephrase it.

For $p > 1$, define $\alpha(p)$ via
$$
  \log \mathbb{E}|X_t - X_s|^p =   \alpha(p)\log|t-s| + O(1).
$$
if such expansion is possible.
Now, define $\alpha_c = \sup\{ \frac{\alpha(p)-1}{p}: p \text{ s.t }\mathbb{E}[|X_t-X_s|^p] <\infty \}$. And then, the question is wether $X$ has a $C^\beta$ version for $\beta>\alpha_c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a Poisson process with intensity $1$. Since $\mathbb{E}(|X_t-X_s|^2)=|t-s|$, it follows that $\alpha \geq 0$ and $\alpha_c \geq 0$. However, Poisson process does not have a continuous modification.

If you want to see sharpness of Kolmogorov-Chentsov theorem for **continuous** processes, then you can consider a deterministic function $f$ which is $\beta$-Hölder for $\beta<\alpha$ but not $\alpha$-Hölder-continuous, e.g. $\alpha=1$ and $$f(t) := t \log(|t|), \qquad t>0.$$ Then consider the deterministic process $X_t := f(t)$. You can easily check that $\alpha_c=1$ but $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ has no modification which is Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: Fully agree with the first example. However, for the second we have $\log \mathbb{E}|X_t - X_0|^p= p \log |t-0|+ \log |\log t |$, the second term is not $O(1)$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Sorry.

Comment: @Kernel We have $$\log |f(t)-f(0|^p = \log (|t|^{p\beta} |t|^{p(1-\beta)} \log(|t|)) = \beta p \log(|t|) + \log(|t|^{p(1-\beta)} \log(|t|))$$ for each $\beta \in (0,1)$. The second term is $O(1)$. Hence, $\alpha_p = \beta p$ is a valid choice for $\beta \in (0,1)$. This gives the desired estimate.

Comment: Just wondering, this was a list of examples rather than a general proof. Is there any theorem stating when this leads to maximal regularity? For instance, in both examples, you had finite moments of all orders.

Comment: @Kernel I am not aware of such a result. However, I doubt that integrability plays a major role. You can destroy integrability by multiplying with some factor which is badly integrable, e.g. (for the 2nd example) $X_t := Z \cdot f(t)$ where $Z$ is some badly integrable random variable (say, with Cauchy distribution).